# Instagram Selenium Web scraping - #Followers

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I am scraping an instagramm page where I need to get the user's:

1. number of posts
2. Number of followers

I managed to login on instagram then search for the user(in this example 'leonardodicaprio') then go to his page. I am not able to select the text though.

Can someone help please?
Thanks!

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from shutil import which
import logging
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import time


class InstatestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'instatest'
    allowed_domains = ['www.instagram.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login']


def __init__(self):
    chrome_option = Options()
    #chrome_option.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_path = which("chromedriver")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path, options = chrome_option)
    driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login")
    logging.info('Website opened...')
    # username = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
    # username = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@name="username"]')   

    username = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@name="username"]')))
    password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@name="password"]')))

    username.clear()
    username.send_keys("username")
    logging.info('Typing Username...')
    password.clear()
    password.send_keys("password")
    logging.info('Typing Password...')
    Login_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@type="submit"]'))).click()
    alert_1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(), "Not Now")]'))).click()
    logging.info('Do NOT save password...')
    alert_2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(), "Not Now")]'))).click()  #search for a text="Not Now"
    logging.info('Do NOT turn notifications on...')
    logging.info('Logging Successful...')

    influencer = "leonardodicaprio"
    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/" + influencer + "/")
    time.sleep(5)

    driver.save_screenshot('Influencer_Home_Page.png')
```

P.S: For the number of followers I want to get the exact number to the nearest digit as found in the title attribute in the selector. Please see picture below:

[insta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIi18.png)

Getting this error when running:

[error in jupyterlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQJhZ.png)

```
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    number_of_post = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href$='profile_posts'] span"))).text
    print(number_of_post)
    number_of_follower = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href$='followed_by_list'] span"))).get_attribute('title')
    print(number_of_follower)
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhUVR.png)

Updated code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from shutil import which
import logging
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import time


class InstatestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'instatest'
    allowed_domains = ['www.instagram.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login']
   
def __init__(self):
    chrome_option = Options()
    #chrome_option.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_path = which("chromedriver")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path, options = chrome_option)
    driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login")
    logging.info('Website opened...')
    # username = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
    # username = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@name="username"]')   

    username = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@name="username"]')))
    password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@name="password"]')))

    username.clear()
    username.send_keys("username")
    logging.info('Typing Username...')
    password.clear()
    password.send_keys("password")
    logging.info('Typing Password...')
    Login_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@type="submit"]'))).click()
    alert_1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(), "Not Now")]'))).click()
    logging.info('Do NOT save password...')
    alert_2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(), "Not Now")]'))).click()  #search for a text="Not Now"
    logging.info('Do NOT turn notifications on...')
    logging.info('Logging Successful...')

    influencer = "leonardodicaprio"
    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/" + influencer + "/")
    time.sleep(5)


    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    number_of_post = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href$='profile_posts'] span"))).text
    print(number_of_post)
    number_of_follower = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href$='followed_by_list'] span"))).get_attribute('title')
    print(number_of_follower)

    driver.save_screenshot('Influencer_Home_Page.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below `CSS_SELECTOR`, to get **number of posts**, and **Number of followers**. to get title, you can use `.get_attribute()`

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
number_of_post = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href$='profile_posts'] span"))).text
print(number_of_post)
number_of_follower = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href$='followed_by_list'] span"))).get_attribute('title')
print(number_of_follower)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Hi @cruisepandey,

Getting the error in my updated post above.

Comment: Where did you get these selectors:
`a[href$='followed_by_list']` and `a[href$='profile_posts'] span`.
I cannot find them in the inspect.

Comment: What is the error ? Are you sure you have copied correctly ?

Comment: See my post above for error - it is the pciture attached.
Plus I have put my full code also.

Comment: I managed to do it by xpath.
`wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)`
`number_of_post = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '(//span[@class="g47SY "])[1]'))).text`
`logging.info("Number of Posts: "+str(number_of_post))`
`number_of_follower = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '(//span[@class="g47SY "])[2]'))).get_attribute('title')`
`logging.info("Number of Followers: "+str(number_of_follower))`

Do you know how I can save these two values in a json or csv?

Comment: You can use pandas to save that info into csv. btw when you used mine css, and print that like this `print(number_of_post)` you got anything printed  ?